# Base class controller with global twig service

Tags: symfony

First of all, I have to say that I have been seeing answers and documentation for several days but none of them answer my question.

The only and simple thing I want to do is to use the twig service as a global service in a BaseController.

This is my code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use App\Service\Configuration;
use App\Utils\Util;


abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{

    protected $twig;
    protected $configuration;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig,Configuration $configuration)
  {
    $this->twig = $twig;
    $this->configuration = $configuration;
  }

}
```

Then in all my controllers extend the twig and configuration service, without having to inject it again & again.

```
//...
//......

/**
 * @Route("/configuration", name="configuration_")
 */
class ConfigurationController extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
       //parent::__construct();

       $this->twig->addGlobal('menuActual', "config");

    }
```

As you can see the only thing I want is to have some `services` global to have everything more organized and also to create some global `shortcuts` for all my `controllers`. In this example I am assigning a global variable to make a link active in the menu of my template and in each controller I have to add a new value for `menuActual`, for example in the `UserController`  the variable would be `addGlobal('menuActual', "users")`.

I think this should be in the good practices of symfony which I don't find :(.

Having to include the `\Twig_Environment` in each controller to assign a variable to the view seems very repetitive to me. This should come by default in the controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've had that problem as well - trying to not have to repeat a bit of code for every controller / action.

I solved it using an event listener:

```yaml
# services.yaml
app.event_listener.controller_action_listener:
    class: App\EventListener\ControllerActionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

```php
#src/EventListener/ControllerActionListener.php
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Controller\BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

/**
 * Class ControllerActionListener
 *
 * @package App\EventListener
 */
class ControllerActionListener
{
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        //fetch the controller class if available
        $controllerClass = null;
        if (!empty($event->getController())) {
            $controllerClass = $event->getController()[0];
        }

        //make sure your global instantiation only fires if the controller extends your base controller
        if ($controllerClass instanceof BaseController) {
            $controllerClass->getTwig()->addGlobal('menuActual', "config");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes found that, the problem I have is that in each controller I have to add a new value for `menuActual`, for example in the `UserController`  the variable would be `addGlobal('menuActual', "users")`, So your example wouldn't solve my problem completely

Comment: You could set a property or method on the classes that extend `BaseController` to handle the class specific part. The event listener then uses / calls that to trigger it. If you use a method you could define it as abstract in the base controller to ensure extending classes define it.

Comment: That's a great idea, let me try and if I have any questions I'll let you know. Thank you very much.

Comment: in the end it's the same thing or I think I don't know, because I have to add `\Twig_Environment $twig` everywhere, and also in the `listener` do `$controllerClass->setTwig()` asks me for the twig parameter :(

Comment: You shouldn't have to - which bit is it that's specifically dynamic based on the controllers? the variable name and value that go into `addGlobal()`?

Comment: Yes exactly in each controller I have to add the name and a new value, both in the constructs and in the different functions of the controller if required. I guess the constructor of each controller has no other way but to inject twig again, right? Excuse my questions but I need to understand.

Comment: Okay I'm stupid, this has nothing to do with symfony and it's PHP I think. In PHP in the contructs you have to pass the services again to overwrite them in BaseController or in the parent class, If not, you won't be able to use it, then in the methods you don't really need to use the constructors and you can access $this->twig without any problems.

Comment: I'm going to give your answer as the correct one, since it has also helped me to have a generic event for all the controllers. Thank you truly and forgive my inexperience.

Comment: You don't have to pass the service again - what you could do is define `protected $twig` in the base controller and then assign that a `\Twig_Environment` instance in the event listener...

Comment: It does not work for the constructor, yes for the methods, but not for the constructor, for the constructor the service should be re-injected. Can you give me an example? This is the listener https://pastebin.com/xbzLsiMv Then in a controller https://pastebin.com/2FzXieS2 , the error is `Call to a member function addGlobal() on null`

Comment: Can you please give me an example?